# Increase blood level and decrease the opponents at same time taking Yoshimitsu?

Tags: pc, tekken-3

I have seen many times Yoshimitsu increasing his own blood level and decreasing the opponents by just holding his opponents head when playing in hard mode against CPU. How can i do that?

Comment: By "blood level" you mean health? This is probably a "Soul Siphon" move, doable from certain special stances. I have played Tekken, oh man, 11 years ago?! O_O So, well, try checking some move lists, like [this](http://www.tekkenzaibatsu.com/tekken3/movelist.php?id=yoshimitsu). If you find what you were looking for, feel free to answer your own question.

Comment: @OrcJMR yes health...

Comment: Since when was Tekken 3 on PC?

Comment: @BadAtPHP It is a playstation game but also available in pc and for you answer since 10 years ago....

Answer (score -1):

two times forward + 1,2 then 1,3

other way is side step + 3,4 then 1,3

Comment: whats 1,2 ,3 and 4 ??